# Deploying python script that uses Firebase to Heroku

Tags: python, firebase, heroku

I have a python script that scrapes a webpage with selenium and posts data to the Firebase realtime database. This script uses the schedule library to run every X hours.

Deploying the script without Firebase, I encounter no errors. When deploying the script with the Firebase code, I get the following message when running `heroku logs --tail`:

> 2020-09-23T18:48:35.044206+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
> status 137 2020-09-23T18:48:35.091567+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State
> changed from starting to crashed 2020-09-24T00:26:53.135632+00:00
> heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
> 2020-09-24T00:27:07.260119+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
> command `python scraper.py` 2020-09-24T00:28:07.677644+00:00
> heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind
> to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Locally, the app works fine with Firebase!

Script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
import schedule
import time
import os
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db

cred = credentials.Certificate('secret-file.json')

firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL' : 'https://a-database-url.com/'
})

# Use Chrome in silent mode
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
op.add_argument("--headless") 
op.add_argument("--no-sandbox") 
op.add_argument("--disable-dev-sh-usage") 


def job():
    PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

    # Heroku driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"), chrome_options=op)

    driver.get("https://a-website.com")
    print("Opening the browser")

    try:
        # Magic..

        time.sleep(1)

        # Magic..

        time.sleep(3)

        # More Magic..

        driver.quit()
    except:
        driver.quit()



schedule.every(5).minutes.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1) # wait one minute
```

Comment: "Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds"—is your script designed to listen for HTTP / HTTPS requests?

Comment: Hi Chris, not in particular or do you mean a driver.get(..url..) ? I'll add my script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds

but it sounds like you don't intend to *run* a web process (one that listens for HTTP requests).

Processes on Heroku are defined in a file called `Procfile`, located in the top-level directory of your project. You probably just need a `worker` instead of a `web` process, e.g.

```
worker: python scraper.py
```

If you already have a `Procfile`, change it from `web:` to `worker:` as shown above. If you *don't* have one, create the file with the preceding content.

Comment: Changed it, pushed it to Heroku and turned on the worker. No strange output, but also no signs of a running scraper

Comment: I seem to get some output print lines. Not what I expected, it looks like the selenium part is not working as it supposed to

Comment: @Rafael, and make sure to check your runtime logs with `heroku logs`. If the scraper isn't running, that might still be in scope here. But if it's running and not doing what you expect, that's a different question.

Comment: I will accept the question, thanks. Locally it will print if the element is found, but remotely on Heroku it doesn't print the line it should, like it would locally..